# How do I write to a file immediately?

Tags: c#, filesystems

I want to keep a logfile, and I am using TextWriter/StreamWriter to write messages to my logfile. I call TextWriter.Flush() after writing the message, but my message still doesn't show up right away. It only shows up when I call Close, and I would rather not reopen and close the file all of the time just to see messages immediately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to try constructing a FileStream yourself passing in the FileOptions.WriteThrough to the constructor. Then construct your StreamWriter with that FileStream. The WriteThrough option bypasses the cache.

Comment: This method was the only one that worked 100% of the time, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could also set the `StreamWriter.AutoFlush` property to true. With this, anything written to the StreamWriter will be written to disk right away (after every call to `Write`).

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.autoflush.aspx) on AutoFlush:

> Gets or sets a value indicating
>   whether the StreamWriter will flush
>   its buffer to the underlying stream
>   after every call to
>   StreamWriter..Write.

Marc

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you open your log file with the read-share access, allowing all subsequent openings of the file for reading, but denying the write access. This way you will be able to monitor the log from another program.